# AJAX, PHP, MySQL. (refreshing tables without blink)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I can't find a solution for this and I can't believe I can't find just one example!

Ok, I have a kind of monitory (PHP / MySQL), refreshed by Javascript. The thing is, that my script reload an entire php page, where I have the MySQL Querys. So, every reload I see a little blink, which is nothing else that the page loading.

This is what I have:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup( {
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#colas').hide();
                            $('#loading').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#colas').show();
                            },
                    success: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#colas').show();
                            }
            });
            var $colas = $("#colas");
            $colas.load("panelColasRealtime.php");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                    $colas.load('panelColasRealtime.php');
            }, 8000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I load "panelColasRealtime.php" right here:

```
<div id="colas"></div>
```

This is working, but I don't want this solution, I don't like that blink. I want to refresh the monitory without reload the php page, just the data.
I think that AJAX is my best choice, but I can't find any example.

Summarizing:

I would like a realtime monitory (every X secods) of my BD and show it . 
If anyone has an example script I would really appreciated it.

Comment: You can't find *any* example of using AJAX with jQuery?  None at all?  Because a Google search for "jQuery AJAX" seems to find *many* examples.  Some of which you seem to be *already using*.  Given that, it's not really clear what you're even asking for at this point...

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. I can't find any example which eliminate the "blink". Maybe what I wanna do is not possible.

Comment: What's "the blink"?  Maybe you can clarify what the actual problem is?

Comment: David,
The blink : "I see a little blink, which is nothing else that the page loading" -> That's the blink.

Comment: If "the blink" is "the page loading" then the solution to "the blink" is to use AJAX so you fetch data from the server without loading the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to refresh the data here is a simple example which refreshes every 5 seconds

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData();
});

var loadData = function() {
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        url: "data_source_page.php",             
        dataType: "html",                   
        success: function(response) {                    
            $(".refresh").html(response);
            setTimeout(loadData, 5000); 
        }
    });
};
```

html

```
<div class="refresh"></div>
```

Comment: That indentation though... 8|

Comment: @Magna: No you didn't :)